# Find the family members id from a single table using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

```
Create Table Member(ParentID nvarchar,childID nvarchar)

insert into Member(1,2)
insert into Member(1,3)
insert into Member(2,4)
insert into Member(3,5)
insert into Member(4,6)
```

How to Find the members id from this table?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ParentId, ChildId FROM Member WHERE ParentId = 1
```

Comment: No it is not fetching all the members. The output should be 1,2,3,4,5,6

Answer (score 1):

```
select ParentID from Member
union
select ChildID from Member
```

Will return all IDs used in either column. If that's not what is actually needed, you may need to provide a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To get Members ID :

> SELECT distinct ParentId from Member;

Comment: No it is not fetching all the members. The output should be 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: That means you want both the parent IDs and child Ids? In that select ParentID from Member
union
select ChildID from Member should be the query